# Boundary testing only works for top/bottom but not left/right

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I tried making a boundary for my pong game for testing but it hasnt worked. The problem is that I set the boundary but it only works for the top and bottom and not the sides. It kind of works for the sides but the boundary is way off.
Here is this code.

> ```
>     let boundary = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
> ```

```
    boundary.friction = 0

    self.physicsBody = boundary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the width of your `SKScene` is higher than the width of your view.

If you are creating a `SKScene` and assigning to the `SKView` programmatically, then you have to initialise the `SKScene` with the size of frame of the view.

```
let scene = GameScene(size:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
```

If you are using an `sks` file. Then You can vary the size of the `SKScene` in the `SKNode` inspector. Like in the image.
[image]

Comment: Where would I put that line of code? Because I put it in the gamescene.swift and it gave me an error. It said that SKView does not have a member named frame. Also I did go into the .sks file and switched the width to 320 but even after I did that, the width worked but the height didnt.

Comment: I find it better to create the scene programmatically without the `sks` file. You can replace `let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene` with my line of code in the `GameViewController` and remove the `if` condition

Comment: can I delete the sks file because honestly it just ruined all of my sizing.

Comment: yes. sure. then you can do programmatically like I mentioned in my answer. You just have to replace that line initialising the scene from the sks file